# Skip package download if already installed

Tags: ansible, apt, deb

I am using ansible to install a deb package and I do not want to download the remote file if the package is already installed. Currently I am doing like this:

```
- name: Check if elasticsearch installed
  become: true
  stat: path=/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
  register: st

- name: Install elasticsearch
  become: yes
  apt:
    deb: https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-5.6.12.deb
    update_cache: true
    state: present
  when: not st.stat.exists
```

Is there a better way to skip the download of the deb package if it is already installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want [package_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/package_facts_module.html#package-facts-module) or, of course, to just cheat and shell out something like `command: dpkg --search elasticsearch`

```
- name: gather installed packages
  package_facts:
- name: Install elasticsearch
  when: elasticsearch not in ansible_facts.packages
```

Unless your question is about how to do that when elasticsearch might have been installed by hand, and not through `dpkg`, in which case your `stat:` and `register:` approach is a sensible one. You may even want to use a `with_items:` to check a few places the file might have been installed, depending on your circumstance